# Handle Ajax calls when user session expires

Tags: ajax, session, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC 5 web application when the user session expires and the user clicks in something in the page that does an AJAX call I was still getting response status 200 with X-Responded-JSON:401.

I have then read and investigated and found a way to solve the problem.

So...added to the **Startup** class **ConfigureAuth** method this

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(
                new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                        Provider =
                            new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                                {

                                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                                    OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                                    {
                                        if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                                        {
                                            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                                        }
                                    }
                            },
                    SlidingExpiration = false,
                    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
                });
```

Just a helper...

```
private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
        {
            IReadableStringCollection query = request.Query;

            if ((query != null) && (query["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;

            return (headers != null) && (headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");
        }
```

This solved my problem locally (in my dev machine) and I am now able to see the 401 in the Ajax calls when the sessions expires or the user logs or when is still trying to access something in a open tab.

My problem is that this work only **locally**. When I have my application in a **server** this Ajax calls still return 200 and I do not understand why....however if I access the application **inside of the box** everything works as expected and I can see the 401 in the browser

Can someone maybe know a better solution for this or maybe the reason why this works locally but not in the server?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution posted in the initial question **works as expected**. This approach was not working in the beginning because of the **custom error pages** that you can define in the **web.config**. It was messing up with the initial solution that I found in the web.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="auto" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/Index" />
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/Index" />
...
...
```

This was redirecting to a different page and because of that was returning **200** instead of **401**.

Thanks